# Can I detect if a guest is using an OSX machine?

Tags: macos

I am writing a tool that will expose an http interface on localhost.  I'd like for it to not be available to a guest using the machine.  I'd like to have the tool refuse connections entirely when a guest is logged in.  Is this possible?  Is there a way to detect this situation?

Comment: Try running `w` in Terminal to see who is logged in. If your tool is developed in Python, you could use `psutil.users()` See here https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Oh good idea!  I'll see if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that guest accounts cannot run concurrently with normal accounts in OSX (at least on recent OSX) so the issue we were concerned about is a non-issue.  You could theoretically detect it with `w` as Mark said in the comments, but it's a thing that won't happen.

Comment: I would have thought a guest user and a regular user could both be logged in at once via `ssh`...

Comment: I don't think so, it looks like running as Guest locks the whole laptop down.